# Syntax error in mysql count(*)

Tags: java, mysql

I have anoying problem with my program and I don't know what is wrong. I've problem with code :

```
 public boolean checkGroup(String groupname){
        connect();
        createtableuser();
        int count = 0;
        String query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `groups` WHERE group = '"+groupname+"';";
        System.out.println(query);
        try{
            statement = connection.createStatement();
            resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query);
            resultSet.next();
            count = resultSet.getInt(1);
        } catch(SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace(System.out);
            return false;
        }
        if(count == 1){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }

    }
```

When I compile i get this error :

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'group='user2'' at line 1
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1054)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4237)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4169)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2617)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2778)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2819)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2768)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1651)
    at server.Database.checkGroup(Database.java:135)
    at server.AddUser$2.actionPerformed(AddUser.java:90)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I don't know what I think about it and where is problem. I please for any help.

PS. Sorry for my English

Comment: It is not a compilation error but rather a run time exception, did u try to execute this query against the database directly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`group` is a keyword: you must quote it with backticks:

```
String query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `groups` WHERE `group` = '"+groupname+"';";
```

Just by the by, naming tables or columns using keywords/reserved words is moronic.

Comment: Oh! It was very helpful, that works! Thank you very much. I didn't know that `group` is keyword in mysql ... Thanks a lot once again. Kindest regards.

Comment: No worries. It's not just mysql; it's a keyword in every SQL database - it's part of the original SQL specification, used in the `GROUP BY` clause.

Answer (score 3):

"group" is a mysql reserved word and should be put inside backticks in the query string.